# Check URL for #hash tag

Tags: javascript

I need to detect once by load if a hash with #comment or #map is in the url to open a spoiled div with the comments and map.
This is the JavaScript that I use to open and close a div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function spoilinout(idinout){
if (document.getElementById) {
var dividinout = document.getElementById(idinout);
dividinout.style.display = (dividinout.style.display=='block'?'none':'block');
} }
</script>
```

How can I detect it?
Thanks
Frank

Comment: What exactly makes a _spoiled_ `<div>`?  Too much CSS??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current URL is stored in `window.location.href` so you can always test:

```
if (window.location.href.match(/\#comment/))
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: don't use match it returns a string with #
it will be better to replace it with location.hash.replace(asdadad

Answer (score 3):

Use `location.hash`

```
if (/#comment|#map/i.test(location.hash)) { /* do your thing */}
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.hash` should give you that hash fragment back.

From there, you can switch on the hash fragment:

```
switch(window.location.hash){
    case "#comment": 
        // comment!
    case "#map":
        // map!
}
```

Comment: where's break in between the case?